# Configuring my device(atmel embedded board) only logging permission to me : deny all other users trying to log in

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, password

First I will explain my needs. I want to configure my device (Atmel Embedded Board), for log in without password through SSH. I Googled it and found out the solution for that. Now I can log in to the device without password.

But here my device is connected to a big network and anyone can log in to the device if they know the password. So I want to configure it so that I'm the only person who can log in to that device without password (Already configured for that) and anyone who I share my key configuration with. Anyone else who tries to log in should fail. It's for security purposes and part of my project.

Please give some threads soon. It will be very helpful for me :(

Answer (score 0):

In your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file you should use the line:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Reload the ssh configuration with:

```
sudo service ssh reload
```

It should now no longer be possible to log in using password based authentication, assuming you're using Ubuntu :)

Comment: By using this  "PasswordAuthentication no" everybody can log in to the device without password i believe . Actually i want to configure like i m the only person permission to  login without password . if else all try , fails

Comment: By using this "PasswordAuthentication no" everybody can log in to the device without password i believe . Actually i want to configure like i m the only person permission to login without password . if else all try , fails –

Comment: That's not the case https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StricterDefaults check the Disable Password Authentication section.